# How CLR verifies that my application is using the right assembly

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I know that it is done by signing assembly with private key.

So here how I see the process ...
When we have the private/public key pair file we can build assembly signing it using this keys.
So what in reallity is done is that compiler opens the 'sk'(or pfx) file and retreives the private key (which I understand is impossible for human) and after signing the assembly with the private key it adds the public key into assembly manifest and that is it I have the strongly named assembly.

So what when I run the application which is referencing that assemly ?
What does CLR to be sure that the assebly is not replaced and nothing was changed?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/StrongNameExplained.aspx

Comment: It rarely does.  [AssemblyVersion] is the primary way it checks.  Only in apps that run in less than full trust does it also check the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quote from CLR via C#

> Signing an assembly with a private key
>   ensures that the holder of the
>   corresponding public key produced the
>   assembly. When the assembly is
>   installed into the GAC, the system
>   hashes the contents of the file
>   containing the manifest and compares
>   the hash value with the RSA digital
>   signature value embedded within the PE
>   file (after unsigning it with the
>   public key). If the values are
>   identical, the file’s contents haven’t
>   been tampered with, and you know that
>   you have the public key that
>   corresponds to the publisher’s private
>   key. In addition, the system hashes
>   the contents of the assembly’s other
>   files and compares the hash values
>   with the hash values stored in the
>   manifest file’s FileDef table. If any
>   of the hash values don’t match, at
>   least one of the assembly’s files has
>   been tampered with, and the assembly
>   will fail to install into the GAC.

Well, here how it works.

When you compile the assembly noting that you want to sign it with already generated public/private key pair file the compiler computes the hash of the assembly (also computes hashes for each file in the assembly and stores the values along with file names in FileDef table) then it signs the hash value with private key and embeds public key in manifest for that assembly.

Now in runtime when the application (assembly) tries to load that signed assembly the assembly is again hashed then CLR gets the public key from the assembly manifest and decrypts the RSA sign and compares the hash value with the sign value. If they are the same than nothing was changed.

Comment: By default the assemblies are not rehashed for verification because of the performance hit. When installing it into the GAC, it's only verified under the installation, not when loaded. You can check the assembly hash yourself, or run it in a sandbox (should also check it). However this might be hard for many developers, and really easy to fail doing it securely.

Answer (score 0):

The strong name contains a fingerprint of the public-key. So the CLR can verify if the puplic-key matches the name, and if the assembly is signed with the corresponding private-key.

Nice article on strong naming:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html

> When you set a reference from one assembly to another, the calling assembly stores a representation of the called assembly's public key. At runtime, the CLR can use this to check that the referenced assembly comes from the correct vendor.

Comment: Yes all the question is that how it checks ?